# Prepopulate Django (non-Model) Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to prepopulate the data in my django form based on some information, but NOT using ModelForm, so I can't just set the instance.

This seems like it should be really easy, but for some reason I can't find any documentation telling me how to do this.  This is my form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
  charfield1 = forms.CharField(max_length=3)
  charfield2 = forms.CharField(max_length=3)
  choicefield = forms.ModelChoiceField(MyModel.objects.all())
```

I tried just doing:

```
form = MyForm()
form.charfield1 = "foo"
form.charfield2 = "bar"
# a model choice field
form.choicefield = MyModel.objects.get(id=3)
```

which does not work.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Try:

```
form = MyForm({'charfield1': 'foo', 'charfield2': 'bar'})
```

The constructor of `Form` objects can take a dictionary of field values. This creates a bound form, which can be used to validate the data and render the form as HTML with the data displayed. See [the forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms) documentation for more details.

**Edit:**

For the sake of completeness, if you do not want to bind the form, and you just want to declare initial values for some fields, you can use the following instead:

```
form = MyForm(initial={'charfield1': 'foo', 'charfield2': 'bar'})
```

See the documentation of [initial values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) for details.

Comment: thanks - this works.  However, it doesn't work with the foreign key to a model.  I tried passing in the model instance itself in the dictionary, which throws an exception, and i tried passing in the pk/id, which doesn't fail, but doesn't pre-load it correctly in my form UI.

Comment: Using the object id should work. I've just tested it with a ModelChoiceField. Could you please show us your form definition?

Comment: I tested again. The following works (2 is an id of an object in the model): MyForm({'charfield1': 'foo', 'charfield2': 'bar', 'choicefield': '2'}). Are you sure you are using an id that exists in the database? I can't think of anything else that may cause this at the moment.

Answer (score 34):

There are two ways of populating a Django form.

The first is to pass a dictionary as the first argument when you instantiate it (or pass it as the `data` kwarg, which is the same thing). This is what you do when you want to use POST data to populate and validate the form.

```
data_dict = {'charfield1': 'data1', 'charfield2': 'data2', 'choicefield': 3}
form = MyForm(data_dict)
```

However, this will trigger *validation* on the form, so only works if you are actually passing in valid and complete data to begin with - otherwise you will start off with errors.

The other way to populate a form is to use the `initial` parameter (documented [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)). This gives initial values for the form fields, but does *not* trigger validation. It's therefore suitable if you're not filling in all values, for example.

```
form = MyForm(initial=data_dict)
```

To populate a choicefield via `initial`, use the pk value.

Comment: Based on the above how do you provide data to customer form fields?

Comment: @Chris, if you have a question and it's not covered by the above, please open a new question and ask it there, with full details.

Comment: It was a side question related to this answer.

Comment: Does the initial value go away when the focus is brought to the filed? I ask because what if you wanted to prefill or initialize the field with data but allow the user to append to it when entering data? Or, better yet, in some cases, force user to append (since the initial value is required by the validation anyway)?

Answer (score 15):

You can use model_to_dict() to convert an instance to a dictionary, and then populate a form with that.  Something like this should work:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
...
my_obj = MyModel.objects.get(abc=123)
form = MyForm(initial=model_to_dict(my_obj))
```

Note: I'm using django version 1.3

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, the `FormView` class-based view way to do this would be to override the `FormView`'s `get_initial` function. `get_initial` returns the initial keyword arguments used by `get_form_kwargs` to instantiate the form.

Docs:

- for `get_initial`, [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/#get_initial),
- for `get_form_kwargs`, [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/#get_form_kwargs).

Sample code:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class MyFormView(FormView):

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(MyFormView, self).get_initial()
        # update initial field defaults with custom set default values:
        initial.update({'charfield1': 'foo', 'charfield2': 'bar'})
        return initial
```