# Is there any method to set default value form.charField()?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have created a form to take input from an HTML page like given bellow:

```
form.py 

  class In_Form(forms.Form):
        Input_peptide  = forms.CharField(label='Start Year ', max_length=100)
        sites_to_be_muted = forms.CharField(label='End Year', max_length=100)
        Amino_acide = forms.CharField(label='End Year ', max_length=100,)
```

**Update:**

Is there any method through which I can set a default value for html form. 
I have tried "initial" but its not working in my case. This form.py is not  related to model its just a form getting user input and processing that data through a script and returning result to a view and rendering output as  "result.html" page:
please help

Comment: `initial` param should work as it's standard feature of form fields ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#initial)). Alternatively you can set field initial value in form `__init__` method.: self.fields['Amino_acide'].initial = 'some value',  (keep in mind to call super previously).

Comment: thanks for your comment, I would be very helpful if  you explain it as a separate answer with example. I am not getting what exactly you want to say. thanks

Comment: Please look at answer to question [Django custom form field initial data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945898/django-custom-form-field-initial-data/7945960#7945960). It contains example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the initial argument when you create a Form instance.

```
form = In_Form(initial={'Input_peptide': '2017'})
```

[Reference](https://djangobook.com/tying-forms-views/#setting-initial-values)