# In Django I want to show a Textarea only during post

Tags: python, html, django

I've a simple page for my django project

1. A form with 2 radio buttons
2. A char field
3. Submit

when Submit is pressed .
in my views.py how can I capture the selected radio button value and value of the char field

When submitted, the same webpage should be reloaded again with a new text area
that text area should contain value of Radio selection + char field concatenation

So far I've created basic form,html view. 
My main issues are

1. I couldn't create a text area that can be hidden based on Get/Post
2. To capture the values from form and concatenate and then show again in the new text area.

views.py

```
def index(request):
form=SfvForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
f = SfvForm(request.POST)
    if f.is_valid():
        form.result_text("hi")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('index.html',{'posted':"posted"},{'form':form})
    else:
        return render_to_response("index.html",{"form":form} , context_instance = RequestContext(request))
else:
    return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class SfvForm(forms.Form):
CHOICES=[('production','production'),('stage','stage')]
selected_env=forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), )
table_name=forms.CharField(required=True)
result_text=forms.CharField() /*Making it as text area is not displaying the form element at all*/
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SFV</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1> hello world!</h1>
    <form id="form" method="post" action="/sfv/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

    </form>
    <form id="form" method="get" action="/sfv/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't your write 2 differents pages? (One with the first form, and one with the second form) and redirect to the second one when the form was successfully submitted?

Comment: Assume it like a calculator . once the result is shown the same page is used for giving more inputs . I don't want the user to traverse back and forth again.

Comment: Ok, did you take a look at my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I'ts because when you redirect with:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('index.html',{'posted':"posted"},{'form':form})
```

You need to [populate the new form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936405/3207406) with the `form` value that you previously posted

```
def index(request):
    form=SfvForm() #<- populate here
```